# PokerTH game, making process failed due to not using C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I'm trying to build PokerTH game in linux. But it fails every time I run the command 'make' because of not using C++ 11. It give this error.

> error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

I have the make file and I added these lines to it,

> CXX=g++
>   CXXFLAGS=-g -Wall -MMD -std=c++11

But still the make fails and gives the same error. Can someone explain me how to get ride of this problem.

This is how I included those above C++ 11 flags to the make file.

```
MAKEFILE      = Makefile  
CXX=g++  
CXXFLAGS=-g -Wall -MMD -std=c++11  
first: make_first  
QMAKE         = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake  
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
```

And then the make file goes like this. Can some one guide me how to solve this problem.

Comment: I suspect they will be overriden later in that Makefile. Can you please do a `grep CXXFLAGS Makefile` and edit your answer?

Comment: One should not edit the makefile directly, but proper makefiles™ will support using environment variables like `CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 make`

Comment: Can you add the entire makefile to your question?

Comment: @hellow I think you're correct. First I need to run this command I've written below, before doing the **make**.  `qmake CONFIG+="official_server" -spec linux-g++ pokerth.pro`. After I run this command this will replace any changes I've done to the MakeFile. So I run the above command first and the edit the MakeFile. But **make** fails.

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri The make file is too long, about 500 lines, I think I've included the most important lines of the makefile

Comment: If this is Qmake, try adding `config += c++11` to the .pro file (or add it on the command line just like `official_server` is added).